# How to solve recursive proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm having some trouble studying for an exam. Specifically, with proving the following:

Let an be the sequence defined recursively by,
$a_1 = 1;
a_2 = 5;$
for $n ≥ 3, a_n = a_{n−1} + 2a_{n-2}$.
Prove that for all $n ∈ N, a_n = 2^n+(−1)^n.$

I used a base case to show $a_3 = 7$.

The I made an inductive hypothesis that $a_k = 2^k+(−1)^k$.

I really don't know where to go from here though. What are the next steps in proving this?

Comment: Use Strong Induction: https://brilliant.org/wiki/strong-induction/

Answer (score 1):

You must assume that the hypothesis is correct for $1,2,3,\cdots ,k$. Then all you need to show is that if $$a_k=2^k+(-1)^k$$ and $$a_{k-1}=2^{k-1}+(-1)^{k-1}$$
then $$a_{k+1}=a_{k}+2a_{k-1}=2^k+(-1)^k+2[2^{k-1}+(-1)^{k-1}]=2^{k+1}+(-1)^{k+1}$$